# How to compile from source and repackage into binaries for distribution?

Tags: rhel, package-management, compiling, rpm-spec, gdal

currently I have compiled and installed the GDAL3.0.4 library from source which also require me to compile and install Proj6.0.0. That is working fine.

So my next part is, i need to package the executables (maybe binaries) so that i can install this in the other server without needing to compile from source again.

I am really new to this. so i have tried lift and shifting the whole folder, tar it and move it into the other server and tried to `sudo make install` GDAL in the new server. it seems to work, but i am having an error `gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libproj.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` while calling the gdalinfo command. this leads me to do the samw for proj6.
but right now, i am stuck with doing the same for proj6 due to g++ not available.

i am running on redhat7.7 which has the repo disabled in this server.

My current approach might be completely wrong, would appreciate some advice. the end goal is to package a version of gdal to be installed in the other servers without needing to compile it from source.

edit: so i found out i could be building it through rpm, so i would need to write my own spec file for that?

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest reading the [RPM Packaging Guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/) to people getting started in packaging rpms.

I suggest installing the “rpmdevtools” package to get yourself started with the rpm spec file. The guide also has several example spec files to use. The `rpmdev-newspec` command can create several types of packages from templates (python, Perl, library, etc).

Once you have a spec file, there are several tools you can use to build the package.  I prefer the `mock` command, because it builds everything in a chrooted build process, so you don’t have to worry about tainting your build system, nor letting your build system taint the packaging process. It also lets you build for other releases, so I can build RHEL packages on my Fedora system.